# Calling members roles

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have this code:

`guild.members.cache.filter(members => members.roles.cache.get('role_id'))`

However, it only returns undefined!

Comment: How? The error is in my question? The code exactly like this? What should be missing?

Comment: Is that enough detail for any reader to reproduce the issue on their own machine? Is it a [mre]? If it is, then it's fine as is. If it's not, can you add enough detail to make it into one?

Comment: your problem is the filter.  Filter is looking for a match criteria... here's an example of how it's used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter